# Find changesets with associated work items using a command-line utility

Tags: tfs

As the title suggests, I am looking for a command-line utility (like `tf.exe`) that will show me the work items that are associated with a list of changesets.  Please no GUI stuff, and especially no command-line utilities that pop up GUI stuff.

I might be persuaded to use a PowerShell cmdlet, but only under duress.  Preferably a good old-fashioned `.exe`.

Comment: Your input is WorkItem(s) and output is Changeset(s) or visa versa?

Comment: Input is changeset(s) and (an) output attribute is work item(s), kinda like the attributes Code Reviewer, Performance Reviewer and Security Reviewer when doing a `tf history /format:detailed`.

Answer (score 4):

With the following snippet you obtain a list of work items that are associated with Changeset '1111'.
Depending on how you retrieve your Changeset(s), I suppose this can be adapted accordingly to fit your needs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace GetWorkItems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://myserver:8080/collection"));
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

            Changeset myChangeset = vcs.GetChangeset(1111);
            WorkItem[] workItems = myChangeset.WorkItems;
            foreach (var workItem in workItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(workItem.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A for effort, but I was hoping for something I didn't have to compile (and find assemblies for).

Comment: I absolutely get what you 're after, but I 'm unaware of an off-the-shelve option for you though...

Comment: Yep - the reason why UNIX has "got" the command-line for 40 years, and Windows still has a long way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the tf program.

```
tf changeset /collection:[url] [changeset#] /noprompt
```

The /noprompt flag prevents the gui from popping up, but you'll have to write something to parse the output. Here's what the output looks like:

```
Changeset: 58
User: Alex
Date: Saturday, December 10, 2011 00:11:41

Comment:
  Fixed bug # 1

Items:
  edit $/netlib/Main/src/NetLib/Samples/Program.cs

Work Items:
  ID Type State    Assigned To Title
  -- ---- -------- ----------- -----------------------
  1  Bug  Resolved Alex        Bug1

Check-in Notes:
  Code Reviewer:
  Performance Reviewer:
  Security Reviewer:
```